# How to list failed targets after building boost?

Tags: windows, boost, mingw-w64

I am building boost on my windows using mingw-4.8.1 and have a few targets which failed. My Problem is that, I do not know which specific targets failed and which were skipped.

> Is there a way to list the failed/skipped targets after the build is completed?

Here the console output:

```
...failed updating 20 targets...
...skipped 28 targets...
...updated 5789 targets...
```

Commands used after downloading a unzipping boost:

```
bootstrap
```

once b2.exe is built. I execute the following command in cmd

```
b2 -j4 --build-dir=build toolset=gcc --build-type=complete --stagedir=C:\SW\Boost -sNO_BZIP2=1
```

*System: Windows 7 ( intel i5 vPro)*
*Compiler: gcc (mingw 4.8.1)*
*Boost: boost 1.61.0*

Comment: Try running the build command again, it should go over the working targets pretty quickly, leaving you with less information. So you can spot more easily which libraries failed. Btw your summary reminds me of a similar problem I had with boost. Using a default user_config.hpp fixed that for me.

Comment: Thank your @JanHenke . I ran it again, and some python libs were not getting built. Excluded those with `--without-python` and ran the command again. Now I have _12 targets failing_ instead of _20_ . Is there no other way?
Also what exactly did the _user_config.hpp_ fix for you? Thank you for your response.

Comment: in ```boost/config/user.hpp``` you can set some global options, mostly about how boost should attempt to be linked to your application. The point is, you should compile the initial boost libraries with the default settings. The python libraries probably failed to compile if you do not have python installed on the system.

Comment: @JanHenke OK. I do have python on the system though. And it is also on the PATH. But do not need it for now. There's something failing which has to do with _serialisation_ and _xml_woarchive.o_ and  _utf8_codecvt_facet_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a little bit of more research resulted in the following.

One can get the build configuration and other build output using 
`b2 [options]`
`b2 --help` reveals the options that can be used. I used the following approaches to diagnose exactly which targets were failing or getting skipped.

**Approach 1**
As suggested by @JanHenke in comments, I ran the same command

```
b2 -j4 --build-dir=build toolset=gcc --build-type=complete --stagedir=C:\SW\Boost -sNO_BZIP2=1
```

(as mentioned in question) again.
*Result*: All tragets that are already built are skipped and only failed ones are shown.
*Problem*: If there are many targets which failed then this just floods the console and it is difficult to find out what is going on.

**Approach 2**
Run the command (see 1) and select all from the command prompt using right mouse click, and then click gain to copy and paste it in a text editor so that is searchable.
*Result*: Usable insights can be drawn by searching for *failed* or *error* keywords
*Problem*: Still not the optimal way as not all the info is vailable on the current cmd window.

**Approach 3**
*Not Done as for me 2. worked, but should surely work*
Create a `batchfile` where in, the command is written and all that is printed on the cmd window, gets logged in a text file using the `>` or `>>` operators.

> *Result*: Will be the best way (known to me till now) to know which exact targets are getting failed and a proper diagnostic action can be taken.

**PS**: *I found that the there is a bug when trying to build serialization library with MinGW. Below the error I am facing and a link to boost forum which talks about the same error.*

```
gcc.compile.c++ build\boost\bin.v2\libs\serialization\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\debug\xml_woarchive.o
In file included from ./boost/archive/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.hpp:23:0,
                 from ./boost/archive/impl/xml_woarchive_impl.ipp:34,
                 from libs\serialization\src\xml_woarchive.cpp:28:
./boost/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.hpp:116:30: error:  
 function 'boost::archive::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet::utf8_codecvt_facet(std::size_t)'
definition is marked dllimport
```

More info [Reference1](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Mingw-test-results-td4684682.html) and [Reference2](http://lists.boost.org/boost-testing/2016/05/8235.php).
Sadly have not found a solution for it yet. Also, it is not the scope of this question.

Comment: **Update**:
As for the failed tragets in my case. They were 8 from Python and 12 from Serialization library. For now I have just excluded them with `--without-LIBRARYNAME` option. Hence the build is clean.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.  After some research, I found this is the best way to see where it got failed.

### My error messages (depends on your machine, you may see different ones):

```
...failed updating 6 targets...
...skipped 6 targets...
...updated 1092 targets...
```

I run ./b2 -q

This will stop at your first errors, in my case:

```
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.8.3/release/threading-multi/bzip2.o
libs/iostreams/src/bzip2.cpp:20:56: fatal error: bzlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include "bzlib.h"  // Julian Seward's "bzip.h" header.
                                                        ^
compilation terminated.

    "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC -m64  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_USE_DEPRECATED -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.8.3/release/threading-multi/bzip2.o" "libs/iostreams/src/bzip2.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.8.3/release/threading-multi/bzip2.o...
...failed updating 1 target...
```

Then you can install the missing dependencies, and see your second missing ones.
To see every single one of your errors, you need to install dependencies on after 
another.  This is good, if you are determined to make a full boost build.
In my case, I compiled bzip library http://www.bzip.org/downloads.html. 
This library is tricky to make.  Boost needs the dynamic version on Linux.

```
make -f Makefile-libbz2_so
```

You have to manually copy the libbz2.so.1.0.6 file to /usr/local/lib
The make two symbolic links

```
libbz2.so.1 -> libbz2.so.1.0.6
libbz2.so -> libbz2.so.1
```

After this my boost can be made and I saw:

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!
```

Or try  ./b2 -s NO_BZIP2=1 to skip